# Is there a limitation in GridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Sitrep: I have a listview / grid view, in a halfassed MVVM style setup.
I have a custom object storing data. in a OberservableCollection.

Everything seems fine until the notify property change event triggers and then the whole application seems to freeze

Note: there is about 24000 items inn this ObservableCollection

Here is the code.

Standard Notify Property Changed

```
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(Object PropertyValue, Object PropertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyValue.ToString()));

            }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
 public ObservableCollection<ObjectModel.EventEntry> EventViewerDisplayData { get; set; } //Property bound to view
 public void DelegatedChangeLog(Object Parameters)
        {
            EventViewerDisplayData = new ObservableCollection<ObjectModel.EventEntry>(new EventViewerMode(Paramters.ToString()); //Evaluates and data gets stored
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EventViewerDisplayData"); //Program Freezes
        }
```

If i limit the list to 1 item it works fine
Any Ideas ?

As Request XML Code:

Mainwindow.xml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EventViewerDisplayData}" DataContext="{Binding EventViewerContext}" Style="{StaticResource GroupedListView}"> 
</ListView>
```

StaticResource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" x:Key="GroupedListView">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="30"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Event ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EventID}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Severity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SeverityName}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Created}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
                                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                </Expander>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                </ListView>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

DataGrouping As requested

```
    private void GridSorting(String Description)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView NewView = System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EventViewerDisplayData);
        NewView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new System.Windows.Data.PropertyGroupDescription(Description));
    }
```

Comment: Post your XAML code as well.

Comment: First of all why you override Template of ListView? Second UI virtualization is enabled by default on ListView but as soon as you do grouping on it, UI virtualization is gone. Hence, your GUI gets freezed because all containers are getting generated at loading time of listView.

Comment: So i cant use grouping on a Listview ?

Comment: If you are using WPF 4.5 you can set `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping = True` on your ListView and it will work. Also, you don't have to override `ControlTemplate` of ListView. Moreover, I didn't see any grouping in your ItemsSource `EventViewerDisplayData`. So, on what property you are grouping on?

Comment: My project is targeted for 4.5.1, i cannot find this property in XAML or C#. please advise.

Comment: It's an attached property. MSDN link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.isvirtualizingwhengrouping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.